# How to return the first value of a list when calling it without index

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of a proprietary language where when you call a list without index, you get the first element by default, instead of returning its string representation.

For example, I'd like the following code to display `42` instead of `[42, 10, 15, 7]`:

```
mylist = [42, 10, 15, 7]
print(mylist)
# prints 42
```

I tried overriding the `__str__` method, but it throws an error because it expects a string to be returned.

```
class GreatList(list):
    def __str__(self):
        return self[0]

mylist = GreatList([42, 10, 15, 7])
print(mylist) # throws TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

Is there a way to supercharge a list and return the first element with the same type when calling it without an index?

Comment: Could you clarify what's wrong with what you've posted, it seems to do what you're asking for.

Comment: As written, I can't return the first element with the same type, it has to be a string. I'm looking to keep the same initial type. In that case, an `int`. I'll clarify

Comment: Just return the string representation of the first element

Comment: I need it to be the same type as the first element.

Comment: As you've found out, it can't be. Why does that matter if you're printing it? Maybe you want `return repr(self[0])`?

Comment: Printing is for the example, I need the same type for further processing: `mylist +1`

Comment: For that you can implement e.g. `__add__`. Read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Answer (score 1):

```py
mylist = [42, 10, 15, 7]

first_value_without_index = next(iter(mylist))
print(first_value_without_index)
```

Comment: This: 1. still returns a string for the first example; and 2. throws an `IndexError` for the second.

Comment: I can recognize the ChatGPT answer; I tried that before asking here

Comment: check now updated code